# kubernetes api OIDC and multi tenant keycloak

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, openid-connect

I've connected my k8s lab to keycloak as SSO provider using OIDC.
I need to use it with multiple keycloak realms and map kubernetes namespaces to the keycloak realms. But `oidc-issuer-url` is static:

```
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/k3s \
    server \
        '--write-kubeconfig-mode=0644' \
        '--flannel-backend=none' \
        '--disable-network-policy' \
        '--token=SECRET' \
        '--datastore-endpoint=postgres://postgres:postgres@mylabpg:5432/k3s' \
        '--kube-apiserver-arg' 'oidc-username-claim=email' \
        '--kube-apiserver-arg' 'oidc-groups-claim=groups' \
        '--kube-apiserver-arg' 'oidc-client-id=k3s' \
        '--kube-apiserver-arg' 'oidc-ca-file=/opt/keycloak/certs/rootCA.crt' \
        '--kube-apiserver-arg' 'oidc-issuer-url=https://mylabkeycloak:8011/realms/master'
```

Is there a way to tell `kubeapi` to use the realm name dynamic?
e.g a header or a query variable to determine the keycloak realm on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've written a custom OIDC provider using `node-oidc-provider` npm module and have added the tenant as a group prefix.

e.g.
tenant1/owner

Now I can handle permissions using Kubernetes RBAC well.